# Explain how to find the 3rd MAX salary in the emp table

Tags: sql, oracle

Anyone will please explain me the runtime execution of the below query:-

```
select distinct sal 
from emp e1 
where 3 = (select count(distinct sal) 
           from emp e2 
           where e1.sal <= e2.sal);
```

Comment: explain better your question  ..  ?

Comment: This is a very old (& inefficient) way to calculate it. Have a look a `DENSE_RANK` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct sal
from emp e1
where 3 = (
        select count(distinct sal)
        from emp e2
        where e1.sal <= e2.sal
        )
```

It's a correlated query which means the subquery runs for each row of the outer query:

The subquery returns the count of distinct salaries that are greater than or equal to the given salary

for example there are following values in emp table:

```
10
20
30
40
```

Say the Outer query is at row with sal = 40. The count returned by the subquery will be 1.

```
for sal = 30, count = 2
for sal = 20, count = 3
for sal = 10, count = 4
```

so only row matching your criteria is row with sal = 20 which is what you wanted.

A better way can be using rank:

```
select distinct sal
from (
    select t.*,
        dense_rank() over (
            order by salary desc
            ) as rnk
    from your_table t
    ) t
where rnk = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a shorter way is when you use the (rather new) function [NTH_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions126.htm#SQLRF30031):

```
SELECT DISTINCT NTH_VALUE(salary, 3) OVER ()
FROM your_table;
```